# URL redirect issue ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, redirect, config

I'm having a problem where the redirects are all redirecting to the same page, I  need them to redirect to an exact matched page not just a partial match.

Ex: product.asp?dtlid=2   should go to page A
    product.asp?dtlid=212 should go to page B

Seems like both both pages go to product A because the 1st number is a 2 in both instances, my code is below.  thanks in advance.

```
<rule name="RedirectP251" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="catalog/details.asp$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="dtlid=2" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sitename.com/producta.mvc" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
<rule name="RedirectP671" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="catalog/details.asp$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="dtlid=211" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sitename.com/productb.mvc" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
```

Comment: Try to append $ in the query string pattern. pattern="dtlib=2$"

Comment: What I had to do was reorder the sequence of the redirects, place them in product ID order, high to low so they would execute correctly, I'm sure there is a better way but had to get this to work quickly.  Thanks.